# Contour Integral along elliptical path

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

The question is:
Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and let $\Gamma$ denote the curve with parameterization

$\gamma(t) = a\cos(t) + ib\sin(t), 0 \leq t \leq 2\pi . $

Compute

$\int_{\Gamma} |z|^2 dz$ .

My first thoughts with the problem was to check if $|z|^2$ was analytic and therefore it would be $0$. It's not analytic and so my next thought was to write $|z|^2$ as $\bar{z}z$. And then use the fact that $\int_{\Gamma} f(z) dz = \int_{a}^{b} f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt$ .

When I do this I get
$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (a^2\cos^2(t) + b^2\sin^2(t))(-a\sin(t) + ib\cos(t)) dt$, that is
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi} (-a^3\cos^2(t)\sin(t) + ia^2b\cos^3(t) - ab^2\sin^3(t) + ib^3\sin^2(t)\cos(t)) dt$$

Taking these integrals I'm getting $0$ for each one and that the entire integral is $0$. I thought this couldn't happen because the function is not analytic. Is it still possible for the integral to be $0$ even if the function isn't analytic? Also is there a different way to do this problem? We haven't gotten to residue theorem in the course yet so I have no idea what it is.

Comment: Hint: symmetry.

Answer (score 1):

Recall for logic:

\begin{array}{|c|c|} \hline
  \text{Conditional statement} &  P\to Q \\
  \text{Converse} & Q\to P \\
  \text{Contrapositive} & \neg Q\to \neg P \\
  \text{Inverse} & \neg P \to \neg Q \\ \hline
\end{array}

- Contrapositive is equivalent to the original conditional statement (if $P$ then $Q$).
- Converse and Inverse are equivalent.
- Converse also holds implying $P$ and $Q$ are necessary and sufficient conditions (if and only if).

If the integrand is holomorphic, then the closed contour integral is zero.  However the converse does not hold.

**Example**

Centroid for area bounded by a closed contour $C$,

\begin{align}
  A &= \frac{1}{2} \oint_C x\, dy-y\, dx \\
  &= \frac{1}{4i} \oint_C \bar z \, dz-z \, d\bar z \\
  &= \frac{1}{4i} \oint_C \bar z \, dz-z \, d\bar z \\
  &= \frac{1}{2i} \oint_C \bar z \, dz \\
  \langle z \rangle &= -\frac{1}{4Ai} \oint_C z^2 \, d\bar z \\
  \langle \bar z \rangle &= -\frac{1}{4Ai} \oint_C \bar z^2 \, dz \\
\end{align}

The last integrand is not analytic but vanishes for central ellipse, though your case is not the centroid formula.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz$ happens to be zero in this case because the curve consists of two symmetric arcs on which $f$ takes the same values: $\gamma(t+\pi) = -\gamma(t)$ and $f(-z) = f(z)$, so that
$$
 \int_\gamma f(z) \, dz = \int_0^{2\pi} f(\gamma(t)) \gamma'(t) \, dt
$$
can be split into integrals $\int_0^{\pi}$ and $\int_\pi^{2\pi}$, which add up to zero.

This does not imply that $f$ is holomorphic. Only if $f$ is continuous and $\int_\gamma f(z) \, dz  = 0$ for **every** closed curve $\gamma$  then $f$ is holomorphic, that is [Morera's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem).